# (AWS S3) Show File Ownership

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are trying to copy/move s3 bucket files that were originally transferred to our bucket from another AWS account.

However, when we try to move these file contents with `aws s3 cp` command we get: `fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`

I think the problem is that someone copied this data over from another account without using `--acl bucket-owner-full-control`. Do you know if there is a way for us to go through and list file owners via the CLI or boto3? Maybe a recursive call to the bucket showing all object owners to each file? Or find anything that isn't owned by our account?

Current permissions of our bucket:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
               "arn:aws:iam::account-user-id:root"
            ]
         },
         "Action": "s3:*",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::customers"
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
               "arn:aws:iam::account-user-id:root"
            ]
         },
         "Action": "s3:*",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::customers/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is what you think it is! You are simply lacking permissions here. What permissions your user(the one which is trying to copy the files) have?

Comment: Hi Riz, I added our current permissions above. I substituted our account id with 'account-user-id' for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Hi @Kyle, I meant your user IAM permissions. with which you try `aws s3 cp`. Also if you are 100% sure the issue is what you think it is, you need to check `Object Ownership` and `Access control list (ACL)` in your bucket's permission tab.

Comment: If these objects are owned by some other account and you were not given full control, which would allow you to take ownership, then look at the [bucket owner enforced setting for Object Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html)  to disable ACLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [recent feature](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-s3-object-ownership-simplify-access-management-data-s3/) in Amazon S3 allows you to **override the ownership settings**:

[image: S3 Edit Object Ownership]

If you configure the bucket with **ACLs disabled**, then you should immediately regain access to all of the objects.